# Proper way to remove last element of delimeter while it's in a string?

Tags: python, string

this is my string:

```
str = "path/to/some/file/name.txt"
```

I want this to become:

```
"path/to/some/file"
```

Any better way besides:

```
new_str = "/".join(str.split("/")[:-1])
```

Comment: `pathlib.Path("path/to/some/file/name.txt").parent.as_posix()`

Comment: `new_str = old_str.rsplit("/",1)[0]`

Comment: Another option is `os.path.dirname(str)`.